# how to match and index 3 dimensions in excell

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

on A i have Date list (12/1/2012, 12/2/2012 etc.) and on G/J/L/N i have list of name (930,320,954 etc.) and the data on lines A21:X186
on A i have also "key" match C/F/P which i need to match to the rows H4, J4, L4, N4
i need to place and match both rows and columns (twice because i have both date and C/F/P)

pls check the attached screen capture with the colors
[screen capture link](https://plus.google.com/photos/106321075253128446682/albums/5929541523968563105?authkey=CK_sp6HPhczEHw)

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As C, F, P appear to always be in the same order you can use a formula like this for H6 copied down

`=INDEX($B$22:$X$186,MATCH($A6,$A$22:$A$186,0)+3,MATCH(G6,$B$21:$X$21,0))`

copy formula to your other columns but change +3 to +1 for the "C" value columns